# HP CodeWars - UPC check digit algorithm

Tags: python

I am preparing for HP CodeWars 2014 by solving previous years' problems, but got stuck in [this problem](http://www.hpcodewars.org/past/cw17/problems/Prob02--CheckDigit.pdf), hoping someone would help me out.

> Here’s the UPC check digit algorithm:
>
> - First, add all the digits in the odd-numbered positions together and    multiply the result by three.
> - Then, add the digits in the even-numbered positions to the result.
> - Next, find modulo 10 of the sum. Modulo calculates the remainder after dividing the sum by 10.
> - Finally, if the remainder is not zero, subtract it from 10.
>
> **Input**
>
> The first line of input contains the number of UPCs that follow. The
>   digits of each UPC will be separated by one  space.
>
> ```
> 6
>
> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
>
> 0 3 6 0 0 0 2 9 1 4 5 
>
> 0 7 3 8 5 2 0 0 9 3 8 
>
> 0 7 0 7 3 4 0 5 3 1 6
>
> 0 4 1 2 2 0 1 8 9 0 4 
>
> 0 3 7 0 0 0 2 0 2 1 4
> ```
>
> **Output**
>
> For each UPC, the program must print the UPC including the calculated
>   check digit. The digits of each UPC should be separated by a single space.
>
> ```
> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 5
>
> 0 3 6 0 0 0 2 9 1 4 5 2
>
> 0 7 3 8 5 2 0 0 9 3 8 5
>
> 0 7 0 7 3 4 0 5 3 1 6 0
>
> 0 4 1 2 2 0 1 8 9 0 4 5
>
> 0 3 7 0 0 0 2 0 2 1 4 1
> ```

Here is my program but it seems to fail somewhere. Please help me find the bug.

```
n=input()
for i in range(1,n+1):
    seq=raw_input()
    ar=seq.split(" ")
    l=len(ar)
    res=0
    sume=0
    sumo=0
    for k in range(0,l):
        if k%2==0:
            sume+=int(ar[k])
        else:
            sumo+=int(ar[k])
    res=(sumo*3+sume)%10
    if res!=0:
        res=10-res
    print seq,res
```

**Error**:

The output is not as expected. I get wrong output, I guess some logical error!

Comment: What does *"seems to fail some where [sic]"* mean? Errors (provide full traceback)? Unexpected outputs (provide inputs and expected and actual outputs)?

Comment: I have re-framed the question. Now please show me which logic did i miss or mess-up with. :)

Comment: **...provide inputs and expected and actual outputs**. Also, you should read e.g. http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Click on the question link for all those! :P

Comment: No, thank you - please put all appropriate information *in the question itself*.

Comment: Well, all set, Now please show me my errors

Comment: **...and actual outputs**. Is the format correct? The values? For all inputs, or just some? What have you tried to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your check for even and odd is the wrong way round. If you change

```
if k%2==0:
    sume+=int(ar[k])
else:
    sumo+=int(ar[k])
```

to

```
if k%2==0:
    sumo+=int(ar[k])
else:
    sume+=int(ar[k])
```

your code generates the correct values. I believe the description assumes the first digit is numbered "1" instead of "0".

Answer (score 0):

```
n=input()
for i in range(1,n+1):
seq=raw_input()
ar=seq.split(" ")
l=len(ar)
res=0
sume=0
sumo=0
for k in range(0,l):
    if k%2==0:
        sume+=int(ar[k])
    else:
        sumo+=int(ar[k])
res=(sumo*3+sume)%10
if res!=0:
    res=10-res
print seq,res
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I believe that more than code, you could explain what you have been done different from OP.